# show table tags from foo.stb; DB error: syntax error near ".stb;"

Tags: tdengine

I need to view all the tag information under a super table, but when I write it like this, it gives an error. Can someone explain it to me?

```
taos> use foo;
Query OK, 0 row(s) affected (0.002940s)

taos> create table stb (ts timestamp, c int) tags(loc int);
Create OK, 0 row(s) affected (0.010996s)

taos> show stables;
          stable_name           |
=================================
 stb                            |
Query OK, 1 row(s) in set (0.007114s)

taos> show table tags from stb;
Query OK, 0 row(s) in set (0.010273s)

taos> show table tags from foo.stb;

DB error: syntax error near ".stb;" (0.000105s)
```

https://docs.taosdata.com/taos-sql/stable/#%E8%8E%B7%E5%8F%96%E8%B6%85%E7%BA%A7%E8%A1%A8%E4%B8%AD%E6%89%80%E6%9C%89%E5%AD%90%E8%A1%A8%E7%9A%84%E6%A0%87%E7%AD%BE%E4%BF%A1%E6%81%AF

Answer (score 1):

Try "show table tags from stb from foo"